# How to handle a pattern in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have this table

```
Date     c1 c2  c3
3/2/2020 a  40  11
3/2/2020 b  21  32
3/2/2020 c  3   54
3/2/2020 d  1   23
3/2/2020 d  22  11 
3/2/2020 d  2   36
3/2/2020 e  31  55
3/2/2020 g  18  24
```

And this is just a snippet of the data in the table based on specific date, the data in the table keeps repeating in the same manner, I.e.

```
Date     c1 c2  c3
3/2/2020 a  40  11
3/2/2020 b  21  32
3/2/2020 c  3  54
3/2/2020 d  1  23
3/2/2020 d  22  11 
3/2/2020 d  2  36
3/2/2020 e  31  55
3/2/2020 g  18  24 
3/3/2020 a  33  1
3/3/2020 b  1  34
3/3/2020 c  33  21
3/3/2020 d  41  44
3/3/2020 d  52  31 
3/3/2020 d  29  26
3/3/2020 e  21  89
3/3/2020 g  48  21
.
.
.
Etc.
```

I want to find the summation of c2 values where the c1 values equal to a and c and update the value of g based on it.

Is there any specific topic that you guys could suggest me to read.
Thanks in advance

Notice that there is a column specifis the same date for each pattern.

Comment: "Same date"? I see no dates

Comment: I didn't add it

Comment: I'd prefer ONE sample data and ONE desired output, based on that input. Data you posted is ... what? Two inputs? There are too many "g" rows. Should all of them have the same summary value of "a" and "c" rows, or ...?

Comment: Each g in each specific date should be the summation of a and c of the same date.

Comment: There isn't a date? You'll get the best help here if you post a full example rather than keep referring to data we can't see

Comment: If the data keeps repeating as you have shown, surely the value that g should be updated to is a constant 43. `UPDATE ... SET c2 = 43 WHERE c1 = 'g'` ?

Comment: It's the schema that is repeating but the values change, anyway. It's not the case, the problem is I want the value calculated by each date, I'll edit the tables so you could have better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> want to find the summation of c2 values where the c1 values equal to a and c and update the value of g based on it.

It sounds like you mean this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET c2 = (SELECT SUM(c2) FROM table WHERE c1 IN ('a','c'))
WHERE c1 = 'g'
```

But after some discourse in the comments whereby you have a date field that defines the larger group within which these elements repeat and you only want the summation to be done within that group, you should coordinate the subquery with the outer one:

```
UPDATE table1
SET c2 = (SELECT SUM(x.c2) FROM table1 x WHERE x.c1 IN ('a','c') and x.date = table1.date)
WHERE c2= 'g';                                                   ------------------------
```

Here's a demo: note that row g is updated to 2, not 3, because one of the dates is not in the group

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91335

Comment: I upvoted because this answers the question that was asked.  However, I suspect that the OP really wants the values only on a particular day, so you should address that in the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It took a long time to pull those particular teeth.. Added :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UPDATE` as following:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE T
SET T.C2 = (
        SELECT SUM(TIN.C2)
        FROM YOUR_TABLE TIN
        WHERE TIN.DATE = T.DATE
        TIN.C1 IN ( 'a',  'c' )
    )
WHERE T.C1 = 'g'
```

Or you can use `MERGE` statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO YOUR_TABLE T
USING 
(SELECT DATE, SUM(C2) AS C2
   FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE C1 IN ( 'a',  'c' )
  GROUP BY DATE) S
ON 
(T.DATE = S.DATE AND T.C1 = 'g')
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET T.C2 = S.C2
```

Cheers!!